# Convert PHP preg_replace to Javascript replace

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Please could someone help me convert the PHP preg_replace to Javascript replace.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$str = 'Test * Testing';
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z 0-9\~\%\.\:\_\\-\&]/', '', $str));
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
var str = 'Test * Testing';
str.replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9\~\%\.\:\_\\-\&]/gi, '');
<script>
```

**EDIT:** The solution suggested is more elegent (**\w**) and I'll be using that in future.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you removed the character class, just keep it:

```
str.replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9~%.:_\\&-]/gi, '');
```

Also `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be shortened to `\w`:

```
str.replace(/[^\w ~%.:\\&-]/gi, '');
```